# How does the success fuction on init.d functions of RHEL works?

Tags: rhel, init-script, daemon, init.d, sysvinit

I am using an Amazon Linux AMI, which is a derivation from RHEL, and it uses SysVint for it's `services`. I am not an experienced Linux user and I am learning more about `services`, so I came across the `functions` script at **`/etc/init.d/functions`** and I just don't understand **how it's `success` and `failure` functions works** (there are other like `warning` too, but they are just the same principle and code).

My `functions` script can be [found here](https://pastebin.com/Xanc9Thr) and the `success` function looks like this:

```
# Log that something succeeded
success() {
  [ "$BOOTUP" != "verbose" -a -z "${LSB:-}" ] && echo_success
  return 0
}

echo_success() {
  [ "$BOOTUP" = "color" ] && $MOVE_TO_COL
  echo -n "["
  [ "$BOOTUP" = "color" ] && $SETCOLOR_SUCCESS
  echo -n $"  OK  "
  [ "$BOOTUP" = "color" ] && $SETCOLOR_NORMAL
  echo -n "]"
  echo -ne "\r"
  return 0
}
```

Frankly I don't understand the `"${LSB:-}"` part since I can't find this `LSB` variable anywhere, but the important part is how the scripts appear to be using the `success` function, for example the last line of the `daemon` function is:

```
[ "$?" -eq 0 ] && success $"$base startup" || failure $"$base startup"
```

Which doesn't make any sense to me because `$"$base startup"` isn't going to be `echoed` since `success` doesn't check for any parameters to `echo` after it. I think the string is being logged but again, I can't see how it would be logged either.

I guess this is really flawed or I am just not understanding something.... the nature of the `success` function is to print a green `[  OK  ]` inline with the cursor, which is causing some weird outputs on some scripts. For example, my `tomcat` script prints `[  OK  ]` on my terminal`s cursor instead of in a new line on top of my cursor, which is really weird:

[image: weird OK]

The text was supposed to be something like `tomcat is running...   [   OK  ]` but since it was printed on my terminal's line, my username and IP cropped most of it.

**So am I getting this wrong, or is the `success` function for RHEL services being used wrongly all over the place?**

Comment: No, your understanding is flawed.   Look at $MOVE_TO_COL

Comment: `$MOVE_TO_COL` prints the `[  OK  ]` on the column `60` and then the `echo_success` script makes an `echo -ne "\r"` that places the cursor back at where it was originally, so the `$MOVE_TO_COL` statement doesn't impact the text flow.

Comment: No, $MOVE_TO_COL does not print anything.  It only moves the cursor to column 60;

Comment: Yes, I meant `$MOVE_TO_COL` was the responsible for printing in column 60 instead of where the cursor is... I thought it was implicitly clear, I am sorry... Still I can't see how this answers anything...

Comment: If you feel like the existing answer solved your problem, please don't forget to accept it with the checkmark. Thank you!

Comment: I liked your answer, but since it's speculative I decided to leave it open.

Comment: As discussed, please remove the link to the SO question, because the linked post does _not_ explain `$LSB`. If you like Jeff's answer, please up-vote it.

Answer (score 2):

You are not wrong, but I wouldn't go so far as to say that the functions are being used *incorrectly*.

> Frankly I don't understand the `"${LSB:-}"` part since I can't find this LSB variable anywhere

Nor can I find $LSB being set anywhere. I can only speculate as to why this variable is being checked; the full test is:

```
[ "$BOOTUP" != "verbose" -a -z "${LSB:-}" ] && echo_success
```

The upshot of the test is to run `echo_success` if the value of the BOOTUP variable is *not* "verbose" and the LSB variable is *not* set. The `${varname:-text}` syntax definition is:

> ${parameter:-word}
>                 Use Default Values.
>   If parameter is unset or null, the expansion of word is substituted.  Otherwise, the value of parameter is substituted.

Here, there's no "word" after the dash, so if $LSB is unset or null, then the whole expansion results in (nothing), which would allow the `-z` test to pass.

My *speculation* is that the logic is there in case you want to change the init script behavior so that it does *not* run these success() or failure() functions.

Secondly,

> how the scripts appear to be using the success function, for example the last line of the daemon function is:

```
[ "$?" -eq 0 ] && success $"$base startup" || failure $"$base startup"
```

You are correct in that these parameters are passed to the functions, but not used. It's harmless to pass in parameters that aren't used -- just inconsistent / confusing! My *speculation* is that previous versions of those functions looked at (perhaps logged?) the passed parameters.

Note that the `init_crypto()` function calls success() (or failure()) *without* parameters!

Comment: I thought the same about the `LSB` but why a variable called as `Linux Standard Base` will have this hability I have no idea.... I just disagree about the incorrect usage, if you try to install tomcat and run its `init script service` you will see it doesn't print any messages correctly at all... I wish I could file a bug report for them but I have no idea where this repo project is located

Comment: the tomcat init script may be doing different things -- my Answer was focused on the /etc/init.d/functions file

Comment: I see your point... It just amazes me to see a complex and wide used service as tomcat with such a broken feature... It makes me wonder if I am not missing something here...